# Changing textcolor to black made dialog title disappear

Tags: android, android-theme

I am using the following theme for the whole application

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.WithActionBar" >
     <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>        
</style>
```

The problem that when I display dialog, the title bar dialog is black and since I  set the text to be black then the text does not appear. How can I fix this for dialogs? Or at least for a specific dialog?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blog.andromo.com/2011/fixing-text-colours-on-an-alertdialog-when-using-theme-light/  It only works post-Honeycomb, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh great it works! I want it for post Honeycomb anyways as I have the light theme for previous. Post it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Done, it is posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a walkthrough on how to do this here](http://blog.andromo.com/2011/fixing-text-colours-on-an-alertdialog-when-using-theme-light/)

In resources, include this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- AlertDialog text color fix thanks to Shawn Castrianni, see: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f0b34621d3a70c4b -->
<style name="AboutDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

To construct your dialog, use this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AboutDialog))
```

Or this if you are using a custom layout:

```
View view = View.inflate(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AboutDialog), R.layout.about_dialog, null);
```